# Displaying graphs to a web page using data from mysql database

Tags: html, mysql, css, jsp, servlets

I need to display a chart/graph in my web page by using the data from  mysql database
the front end I'm using is HTML, CSS, JSP, and the backend I'm using is servlets and mysql.
Is there any solutions?. I've googled it but I cant find my requirement or at least it's match. I need your suggestions.

Comment: Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/ ?

Comment: A javascript solution feeding it the values from JSP would be easiest. Any Java solution will create an image you'll have to figure out how to serve.